# How to prove that

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Given that  fulfills the following condition: there is a real number 0<<1 so for all-natural ≥2:
|$a_{n+1}−_|<c |(_^2−_{−1}^2)|$ where  $|a_n|<2$

To prove : ($a_n$) is convergent

Now I was able to prove that ($a_n$) is convergent for the case where sum of consecutive terms of the sequence is more than or equal to one
How should I go about solving the case where their sum will be less than one ??

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Let $a_n=0$ for $n$ even and $a_n=1.5$ for $n$ odd. Let $\frac  2 3 <c<1$. Then $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=1.5 <c(1.5)^{2} <|a_n^{2}-a_{n-1}^{2}|$ for all $n$ but $(a_n)$ is not convergent.